# Disable the swap in WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm developing windows phone 8 application.
How I can disable the swap between the items in the pivot page ? since I  disabled the `IsHitTestVisible` property to do that.
But When I used it ;  controls in the item page  doesn't accept input from user?
How I can disable the swap ? and allow the input from the user in the same time ?

Comment: do you mean that you don't want to allow the pivot to change (i.e. swiping from left to right), but that you still want controls on the pivot to function as normal?

Comment: Yes Exactly .I want to disable the swap , because  I use a button to move between the pivot items "mypivot.selectitem=itemone;"

Comment: did you try `IsEnabled=false` or `IsTabStop=false`?

Comment: Additionally, I'm assuming this is sort of going against how this control was intended to be used, so I'm wondering if it would just make more sense to have separate `Page`s and have your buttons navigate to them accordingly (instead of using a Pivot Control at all).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to stop the Pivot on WP8 for switching PivotItems, use the new Pivot.IsLocked=true property. Read more about it here @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.pivot.islocked(v=vs.105).aspx

For example, this code snippet shows how to use Pivot.IsLocked on WP8:

```xml
<phone:Pivot IsLocked="True">
    <phone:PivotItem Header="Foo">
        <TextBox />
    </phone:PivotItem>
    <phone:PivotItem Content="Bar" Header="Bar" />
    <phone:PivotItem Content="Baz" Header="Baz" />
</phone:Pivot>
```

When you run this code snippet you can see the Pivot only shows the first PivotItem but you can still interact with it (which isn't possible if you simply set IsEnabled=False).

[image: Pivot with only the first item]

For WP7, use there's a LockablePivot in the Windows Phone toolkit that support this same property. Read more about it here @ http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-Toolkit-LockablePivot-in-depth

Comment: Thank you ; It's working well ; However I add a button to allow the user to go to the next item without using the swap.

 if (MyPivot.IsLocked == true)
        {
            MyPivot.IsLocked = false;
            MyPivot.SelectedItem = itemtwo;
            
        }
        MyPivot.IsLocked = true;
           
        }